# Taking a count from file, I want to print no of variables using shell/bash

Tags: bash, shell

Taking count from file, say if count = 5, I want to print 5 variables. i.e. A B C D E.
If count = 2, Print 2 variables A B, etc.

I have tried using the ASCII values but couldn't go through it.

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
    count=5; a=0; 
    printf "\x$(printf %x '65+$a')"; 
    count=count+1; 
done
```

if count = 5, I want to print 5 variables. i.e. A B C D E. If count = 2, Print 2 variables A B, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a program that matches your style that does what you are looking for:

```
a=0
for i in {1..5}; do 
    printf "\x$(printf %x $(( 65 + a )) )"; 
    a=$((a+1)); 
done
```

The first thing to note is that in order to do math in bash, you'll need to use the  $(( )) operation.    Above, you can see I replaced you '65+$a' with $(( 65 + a )) .  That's the big news that you need to get math done.

There were a couple of other little issues, but you were stuck on the $(()) stuff so they weren't clear yet.  Incidentally, the 'a' variable can be completely removed from the program to just use the 'i' variable like this:

```
for i in {1..5}; do 
    printf "\x$(printf %x $(( 64 + i  )) )"; 
done
```

I had to change the constant to 64 since we are now counting starting at 1.

The {1..5} expression is a good short cut for 1 2 3 4 5, but you won't be able to put a variable into it.  So, if you need to add a count variable back in, consider using the seq program instead like this:

```
count=$1
for i in $(seq 1 $count); do 
    printf "\x$(printf %x $(( 64 + i  )) )"; 
done
```

Note that $() is different than the math operator $(()).  $() runs a subcommand returning the results.

Comment: Just to inform, The Previous suggestion provided by you also did work.

to be precise as below.

count=30

iter=0
for letter in {A..Z}
do
  printf "$letter\n"
  [ $(( ++iter ))  -eq  $count ] && break
done

Comment: doesn't this fail once you reach 27?

Comment: Yes, its does fails once you reach 27. But as I was aware that the file count in my environment is never going to cross the limit. It worked for me.
But for invariably larger counts, the other option could be considered.

Comment: @Learner - I didn't think that my first answer was helpful - it was just a fun way of approaching the question, but it really didn't explain where your mistake was.

Answer (score 0):

### method 1: simple brace expansion

```
#!/bin/bash

# generate a lookup table
vars=( - $(echo {A..Z}) )

# use the elements
for i in {1..5}; do
    echo ${vars[$i]}
done
```

- `{A..Z}` generates 26 strings: `A`, `B`, ..., `Z`
- which get stored in an array variable by `vars=(`...`)`
- we prepend a `-` that we'll ignore
- we can then do 1-based indexing into the array
- limited to 26 variables (or whatever range we choose)

### method 2: multiple brace expansion to generate arbitrary long variables

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 count"
    exit
fi

cmd='{A..Z}'
for (( i=$1; i>26; i=i/26 )); do
    cmd="${A..Z}$cmd"
done
vars=( $(eval echo $cmd) )

for (( i=0; i<$1; i++ )); do
   echo ${vars[$i]}
done
```

- `i/26` does integer division (throws away the remainder)
- I'm lazy and generate "more than enough" variables rather than attempting to calculate how many is "exactly enough"
- `{a..b}{a..b}{a..b}` becomes `aaa aab aba abb baa bab bba bbb`
- using `eval` lets us do the brace expansion without knowing in advance how many sets are needed

Sample output:

```
$ mkvar.sh 10000 |fmt -64 | tail -5
ORY ORZ OSA OSB OSC OSD OSE OSF OSG OSH OSI OSJ OSK OSL OSM
OSN OSO OSP OSQ OSR OSS OST OSU OSV OSW OSX OSY OSZ OTA OTB
OTC OTD OTE OTF OTG OTH OTI OTJ OTK OTL OTM OTN OTO OTP OTQ
OTR OTS OTT OTU OTV OTW OTX OTY OTZ OUA OUB OUC OUD OUE OUF
OUG OUH OUI OUJ OUK OUL OUM OUN OUO OUP
```